# JavaScript getting stuck in a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to perform a simple animation that I would like to happen after a successful return of an AJAX call.

```
$('#result').click(function(){
    $(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){
    $('html, body').on("scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup touchmove", function(){
        $('html, body').stop();
    });
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#result').position().top
    }, 500, function(){
        $('html, body').off("scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup touchmove");
    });

    });
});
```

The problem is that sometimes, not always, the animation does not seem to want to exit in that it causes jerky movements and a constant return to the top of the div if the user attempts to scroll away. When I remove the ajaxSuccess requirement, the problem does not occur. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attaching a new `ajaxSuccess` callback every time the user clicks on `#result`.

This means that if the user clicked on `#result` N times, then N different functions are attached to be executed whenever an ajax request completes successfully. And each function will try to animate `$('html, body')`

**Solution:** Move your code out of `$('#result').click` function **or** unbind previous handlers before binding a new one.

And here is the simplified example of what is happening. Try to click two buttons one after another:

```js
$("#one").click(() => {
    console.log("Clicked First")
    $("#two").click(() => console.log("Clicked Second"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id=one>First</button>
<button id=two>Second</button>
```

Comment: I suppose it would also be possible to add a line for removing the ajaxSuccess event handler. true?

Comment: @user3829444 Right, you could do something like `$(document).unbind("ajaxSuccess", handler)`, but to do that you need to assign the callback function to a variable `handler` first

Comment: Or just `.off(”ajaxSuccess”)` to remove all handlers

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to stop mousewheel, scroll etc. movement by using stop() function.

animate function won't be disturbed until it has reached the document top.

This would do:

```
$('#result').click(function(){
    $(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#result').position().top
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: I want to stop the animation if the user makes an input.